# Is there any way to return it properly?

Tags: python

Spyder and others IDE says it is completely fine, although it does no run.

```
def tiempo_transferencia(tamano: float, ancho_banda: int)-> str:
tamano = 80
ancho_banda = 50
tamano_en_MB = round(tamano*1024,2)
ancho_banda_real= ancho_banda*0,125
tiempo = tamano_en_MB / ancho_banda_real
x =  tiempo // 3600
residuo1 = tiempo%3600
Y = residuo1// 60
residuo2 = residuo1%60
Z = residuo2 // 1
return "el archivo tardará" + str(x) + "horas" +str(Y)+ "minutos y" +str(Z) + "segundos en transferirse"
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? Also, how do you call this?

Comment: try to write all the element that you want return in a variable and then return the variable

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It says "unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Comment: Indentation is syntactically significant in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure the code is indented in the function.
2. Make sure that you are calling the function, as the function definition by itself isn't going to do anything. For example: `print(tiempo_transferencia(3.0, 5))`
3. Why do you have parameters in your function when you have set the variables to a fixed value within the function? Remove `tamano = 80` and `ancho_banda = 50`.
4. `ancho_banda*0,125` is not valid as Python takes this as a tuple. This should be a single number as you are using this to in some division in the next line. I don't know what you are trying to do in this line so I cannot give a suggestion on improvement other than to make it a single integer without that comma there.

These changes should look something like this:

```
def tiempo_transferencia(tamano: float, ancho_banda: int)-> int:
    tamano_en_MB = round(tamano*1024,2)
    ancho_banda_real= ancho_banda*0,125 # Sort this line out
    tiempo = tamano_en_MB / ancho_banda_real
    x =  tiempo // 3600
    residuo1 = tiempo%3600
    Y = residuo1// 60
    residuo2 = residuo1%60
    Z = residuo2 // 1
    return "el archivo tardará" + str(x) + "horas" +str(Y)+ "minutos y" +str(Z) + 
    "segundos en transferirse"

print(tiempo_transferencia(3.0, 5)) # Example of function call
```

If you are getting an error in the console, make sure you include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put the string into variable and return the variable:

```
def tiempo_transferencia(tamano: float, ancho_banda: int)-> int:
     tamano = 80
     ancho_banda = 50
     tamano_en_MB = round(tamano*1024,2)
     ancho_banda_real= ancho_banda*0,125
     tiempo = tamano_en_MB / ancho_banda_real
     x =  tiempo // 3600
     residuo1 = tiempo%3600
     Y = residuo1// 60
     residuo2 = residuo1%60
     Z = residuo2 // 1
     variable_to_return = "el archivo tardará" + str(x) + "horas" +str(Y)+ "minutos y" +str(Z) + "segundos en transferirse"
    return variable_to_return
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe on the line below:

```
ancho_banda_real= ancho_banda*0,125
```

The code  ancho_banda*0,125 is considered as a tuple, so if you want to multiply ancho_banda by  decimal 0.125, try replacing 0,125 by 0.125.